# Como restarle dias a la fecha actual mysql?

Tags: mysql

he estado pensando como resolver esto, tengo la fecha actual (le cambié la fecha a la pc) y estoy haciendo una resta entre la fecha actual y cierto numero de días, la cuestion es que estoy usando un not between en el WHERE ya que necesito que me aparezcan unicamente los resultados que no están comprendidos entre esas fechas. adjunto el query:

```
select 
    nombre, 
    max(fecha) fecha,
    curdate() fecha_actual,
    curdate() - interval p.dias day resta_dias,
    sum(cantidad) saldo 
from 
    credito cre 
    join cliente cli 
        on cli.id=cre.id_cliente 
    join periodo p
        on p.id=cre.id_periodo
where
    fecha not BETWEEN curdate() and CURDATE() - INTERVAL p.dias day
group by 
    id_cliente
```

el campo periodo.dias tiene un numero plano (1,2,7,20, etc) entonces al darle esto me aparece los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el detalle es que como pueden ver la 2da fila donde está "Juan Lopez" la fecha que tiene es 2020-11-03 y la columna resta_dias tiene la misma fecha, entonces segun el query arriba al usar NOT BETWEEN no tendría que aparecer la segunda fila, sino que solo la primera. y eso es lo que quiero realmente, que en esta opción encontrar una solución para que solo aparezca la 1era fila, solo tengo estos 2 datos de ejemplo, pero al tener más quisiera que me trabajara como deseo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Igual el problema está en los datos, ¿podrías modificar la pregunta aportando un dataset de muestra para hacer pruebas y ver qué vemos? (phpMyAdmin, exportar)

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, el query está un 99% bueno. he aquí la solución:

```
select 
    nombre, 
    max(fecha) fecha,
    curdate() fecha_actual,
    curdate() - interval p.dias day resta_dias,
    sum(cantidad) saldo 
from 
    credito cre 
    join cliente cli 
        on cli.id=cre.id_cliente 
    join periodo p
        on p.id=cre.id_periodo
where
    fecha not BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL p.dias day and curdate()
group by 
    id_cliente;
```

es de cambiar la condición de esto:

```
fecha not BETWEEN curdate() and CURDATE() - INTERVAL p.dias day
```

a esto:

```
fecha not BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL p.dias day and curdate().
```

espero que a alguien mas tambien le sirva, por lo que pude deducir, no puedo colocar el intervalo de fechas de mayor a menor, tiene que ser de menor a mayor.